# =importdata() function unable to fetch URL seconds after it was working

Tags: google-sheets

It seems all of the importdata functions are unable to fetch my URLs—seconds after it would work. Is there any reason for this cause? I removed all scripts and triggers in the workbook and now I'm seriously lost on what to do. [image]

Comment: This is a recent phenomenon. Last week all of my scripts were working fine, regarding all of my importdata() functions.

Answer (score 0):

I set up jumpcloud 2fa with my workplace admin and it seems to load properly. May have been a security implementation that prevented proper loading.